# Images not working in Opera and Mozilla

Tags: html, css, opera, mozilla

Hello there everybody,

I am currently working on a page that has an HD background image (1900x1080) fixed, always visible in the viewport of the browser, that is actually the background image.

Everything is ok with this till the point of testing it in different browsers.
I tested the site in different browsers both on desktop and mobile platforms and it worked in each one except 2 of them that are Opera (12.15) and Mozilla (20.0.1) (both the latest version at this moment) and on the mobile platform on an Android smartphone with its default browser (in which is working) and the mobile version of Opera (that is not working).

The site is working so far on the following browsers: Maxthon Cloud browser 4.0.5.4000, Google Chrome 26. 0.1410.64, Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2), Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 (It's working even on IE!!! >.<), as about the mobile platform I already told you above.

The site is the following: [bulanmaster.herobo.com](http://www.bulanmaster.herobo.com)

Oh and by the way: I didn't use anything else but HTML and CSS.

Thank you in advance.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image source has a wrong location. Change it from "photos\dj.jpg" to "photos/dj.jpg"

Comment: Would it not also be less of a hassle with divs to set the image as the background of the body element in CSS?

Comment: Yes, background image is better and faster.

Comment: OMG >.< shame on me :( Thank you very much for both. I didn't know that as background image is faster. Thank you :)

Comment: Tho it is interesting that some of the browsers accept "\" whilst the other ones don't. :P

Comment: Seems like as a background image is not working on mobile platforms.